# How to Navigate through the table inside a fieldset

Tags: jquery

There will be a Table inside a Fieldset, I am using below code to access that table. But it is not working.

```
 $('Fieldset_A TABLE TBODY TR').each(function()
  {
     .......
  }
```

My HTML Code is like this

```
 <div class="gridanswers"><fieldset id="Fieldset_A">
 <table class="yyyy">.............</table>
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 3):

assuming fieldset_A is an id you need to identify it as such like so

```
 $('#Fieldset_A TABLE TBODY TR').each(function()....
```

if it is a class then

```
$('.Fieldset_A TABLE TBODY TR').each(function()
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/TPbN3/)